# How to change final HTML output using pdf2dom with Java?

Tags: java

I want to convert a PDF document to an HTML file, and have my HTML output as close as possible as the original PDF. To do so, I am using Pdf2Dom. However, for business reasons I need to move the style div from the header, to the body section.
The naive solution I tried is to get the text content of the style div, and to write it at the end of my document like so:

```
 public InputStream fileToHtml(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));
    PDFDomTree parser = new PDFDomTree();
    PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(inputStream);
    Document dom = parser.createDOM(pdf);

    Node styleNode = dom.getElementsByTagName("style").item(0);
  
    String content = style.getTextContent();
    outputStream.write(("<style>" + content + "</style>").getBytes());
    parser.writeText(pdf, writer);


    return new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
}
```

But I have two issues with this solution:

1. style div is not in the body section, but at the very end of the document, which I do not want
2. I have the style div duplicated, one at the end of the document (see 1.), and one still in the header section, as it has not been removed.

Therefore, I tried another approach by trying to modify the nodes before the conversion like so:

```
 public InputStream fileToHtml(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));
    PDFDomTree parser = new PDFDomTree();
    PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(inputStream);
    Document dom = parser.createDOM(pdf);

    Node node = dom.getElementsByTagName("body").item(0);

    // I just change the content of the body part to check if the final HTML output changed 
    node.setTextContent("my new content");
    // I do not get "my new content" in the final HTML output, however the content of the node is "my new content" according to the terminal
    System.out.println(node.getTextContent());

    parser.writeText(pdf, writer);


    return new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
}
```

However, I do not get a simple "my new content" as expected, but the original pdf content.

Last thing I tried is to create a new document, from the initial document to manipulate it and THEN, convert it (in this example I am not modifying the content at all, I just want to create a new document from the original one just to check if this approach could work):

```
 public InputStream fileToHtml(InputStream inputStream) throws throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException , TransformerException {

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));
    PDFDomTree parser = new PDFDomTree();
    PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(inputStream);
    Document dom = parser.createDOM(pdf);

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Source xmlSource = new DOMSource(dom);
    Result outputTarget = new StreamResult(outputStream1);
    TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(xmlSource, outputTarget);
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream1.toByteArray());
    NodeList style = 
    PDDocument newPdf = PDDocument.load(is);

    parser.writeText(newPdf, writer);


    return new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
}
```

However, I get the following error message: `java.io.IOException: Error: End-of-File, expected line`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by using Jsoup, which is an HTML parser. I first parse the PDF file, then convert it to an inputstream that I will pass to Jsoup parser and then apply my modifications there:

```
    PDFDomTree parser = new PDFDomTree();
    PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(inputStream);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    org.w3c.dom.Document dom = parser.createDOM(pdf);
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Source xmlSource = new DOMSource(dom);
    Result outputTarget = new StreamResult(byteArrayOutputStream);
    TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(xmlSource, outputTarget);
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());

    org.jsoup.nodes.Document htmlDoc = Jsoup.parse(is, null, "");
    Element body = htmlDoc.body();
    body.append(pdf2domStyle);
    outputStream.write(body.outerHtml().getBytes());

    outputStream.close();
    byteArrayOutputStream.close();

    return new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
```